# Is it possible to save the Crime Net public server filter settings?

Tags: payday-2

Each time you enter Crime Net, the public server filters are always returned back to their default values - showing games of any difficulty, contract, etc.

[image]

Is it possible to save the public server filters settings rather than having to set them individually each time you enter Crime Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible so far: I've been looking after the same feature, and all I could find were complaining steamcommunity threads, just like [this one](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864978109380927654/).

> Please make the Crime.net filters persistent
>   It gets annoying to have to set six different parameters every time I go to the Crime.net
>   looking for a specific job. I'm sure many others would also appreciate this.

Also, note that, as [one of the answers](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864978109380927654/#c864978109386072449) states, the search filters only reset if you close the game, or if you leave a lobby you've just hosted.